# How much specialty grain should you use in each steeping bag?

Tags: first-time-brewer, steeping, specialty-grains, extract-brewing

I'm doing my very first steeping brew (2nd brew ever), and I've got about 3 lbs of specialty grains total that go into my recipe.  I've lightly crushed the grains, and I'm ready to put them in the steeping bag(s), but I'm not sure how much should go in each bag.  should I just put all of it in one bag, use a different bag for each grain, or just split it in half so there's more contact to the water?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to split each grain into its own bag, unless you want to remove them at different time intervals for whatever reason (hint: you don't. ;)  If they'll all comfortably fit in one bag, great.  If not split them up.  Maximizing water contact is … probably negligible, here.

Comment: To be clear, you want to make sure all of the steeping grains are wetted - no dry spots or "dough balls" in the middle of the bag.